# Random Color Generation in particular range

Tags: c#, windows-8, winrt-xaml

I need to generate a random color for each item in my `gridview`. My requirement is that I must generate these colors between, for example, one shade of blue and another shade of blue. i.e. all colors must be within that range. I have a start color and an end color and I have a random object to generate bytes. How do I ensure that the colors generated stay within the given range? I need to write this in `C#` for `Windows 8`. The only color generation option it shows me in `Windows.UI.Color` is the `FromArgb` method. Any ideas on how I could achieve that?

Comment: Are colours linear? Will the red and blue components remain unchanged?

Comment: http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: Yeah. The start and end colors will always be between two shades of, say, blue or two shades of red.

Comment: And I have tried to generate random colours using rnd.GetNext and throwing those bytes into the Color.FromArgb method.. but I am unable to control the output like I'd want to.

Comment: The single `Int32` overload of `Color.Argb` uses a compound of the three (or four) colour components so adjusting that value will not affect the colour in a linear fashion. A colour is made of at least three components so cannot be treated as a linear value.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
Random random = new Random();
byte randomNumber = (byte) random.Next(20, 256);
Color blueish = Color.FromRgb(20, 20, randomNumber);
```

Should give you a blueish color between 20 and 255 with fixed red and green value's

Comment: Thanks! On the lines of what I was looking for. Works well! :)

Answer (score 2):

Ok, given your limited example,

```
static Color RandomBlue(byte minBlue, byte maxBlue, byte red, byte green)
{
    var blue = Random.Next(minBlue, maxBlue);
    return Color.FromArgb(red, green, blue);
}
```

will generate a `Color` or random blueness within a range.